# Can someone ask questions about a particular website for WordPress theme testing?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I want to ask how can one do WordPress theme testing using [WPTest](http://wptest.io/). I have read that specific plugin issues will not be covered so I am wondering if it fits or not. Thanks

Comment: My guess is it will be off topic. But lets see what other experienced members think..

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but it's equal to

> How to do [X] with [software/hard ware/service Y]

In short, please stay away from such questions and consult their support instead. Thanks.